# How to set keychain capabilities on a ios dowloaded project?

Tags: ios, xcode, vpn

I'm new on ios.

I downloaded a [vpn project](https://github.com/passepartoutvpn/passepartout-ios) from github, and I am able to run it on my iPhone but after importing the vpn profile and clicking on "enable", it doesn't connect to my vpn

I already know it's because some "keychain sharing capabilities" like written in the Readme, that i don't know at all (i'm still in an android world :)

Below is the error:

> 2019-11-10 15:28:28.127193+0200 Passepartout[1331:642380] 15:28:28.127 :heart: ERROR GracefulVPN.reconnect():83 - Could not reconnect: credentials(details: “keychain.set()“)

How can I set "App Groups and Keychain Sharing capabilities" for the project to work entirely ?

What I changed in the project is the Bundle's name only which appears in my developer account

Thank you for your help